# Access ASP.NET Core 6 Web API application using Lambda function url

Tags: aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi, aws-api-gateway, .net-6.0

How to access ASP.NET Core 6 Web API from AWS Lambda using function url instead of API Gateway which has a timeout of 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can expose the Web API using function url using HttpApi but be aware that its a public url.

```
builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.HttpApi);
```